# call the LABS.GENERATIVEAI function in VBA

Tags: vba

How can the Excel [LABS.GENERATIVEAI](https://github.com/microsoft/Excel-Labs/tree/main) function be called in VBA?

The Excel Labs add-in, which enables this function, can be installed from "Home -> Add-ins". Then, the function can be used in worksheets.

My unsuccessful attempts included:

- Using WorksheetFunction.Labs... (this function is not available here)
- Application.Run("LABS.GENERATIVEAI", "question...")
- Application.Run("ExcelLabs.LABS.GENERATIVEAI", "question...")

Additionally, it is not listed in the Object Browser.

Comment: You can use it inside Excel cell or named formula, but I don't think you can call it in VBA.